# How can I check the type of an exception from within a function?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
        catch (ServiceException e) { se(e); return View("CreateEdit", vm); }
        catch (Exception e) { ex(e); return View("CreateEdit", vm); }
        return RedirectToAction("ShowSummary", new {
                    ds = vm.Meta.DataSourceID
        });

    protected void se(ServiceException e) {
        ModelState.Merge(e.Errors);
    }
    protected void ex(Exception e) {
        Trace.Write(e);
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Database access error: " + e.Message);
    }
```

I would like to change this to something like:

```
        catch (Exception e) { processException(e); return View("CreateEdit", vm); }
```

Is there a way that I can add code to a processException function that would be able 
to check what kind of exception it is and then do action depending on if it is a ServiceException 
or just a general exception? I just want to put all my exception handling in one place
and then call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `is` keyword like this

```
protected void processException(Exception e) {
    if (e is XXXException)
    {
        this.doThis();
    }
    else if (e is YYYException)
    {
        this.doThat();
    }
}
```

You can also use a switch statement and test the type of the `e` but IMO `is` is easier and better

Comment: I will agree that `is` would be the easiest method for the questions situation. A switch would be better if they were many.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `typeOf(e)` or `e.GetType()` and then do a switch or if statement on that.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, we use this extensively in database exception handling.

```
public void processException(Exception ex)
{
   if (ex is System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
   {
      // Do something
   }
   else if (ex is AnotherException)
   {
      // Do something else
   }
}
```

Comment: And...why wouldn't you just catch the appropriately derived type of exception? Then you'd *know* which type it is. You should almost never catch `System.Exception` anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray: because the OP wanted a central exception handler. If you have 50 methods that all need to process an SqlException in the same way, then it is much easier and more certain to send all exceptions to a central exception handler than to have 50 discrete catch/catch sets of code.